# How to select which member is exported to COM when using explicit interface implementation?

Tags: c#, vbscript, com

If my class implements `IEnumerable`, I can use VBScript's `For Each` loop:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ProgId("Stackoverflow.MyIssues")]
[Guid("7D392CB1-9080-49D0-B9CE-05B214B2C448")]
public class MyIssue : IEnumerable
{
  readonly List<string> issues = new List<string>(new string[] { "foo", "bar" });

  public string this[int index]
  {
    get { return issues[index]; }
  }

  public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
  {
    return issues.GetEnumerator();
  }
}


Dim o : Set o = CreateObject("Stackoverflow.MyIssues")

Dim i
For Each i In o
  WScript.Echo i
Next
```

If I change the interface to `IEnumerable<string>` (so C#'s `foreach` loop uses `string` instead of `object`):

```
public class MyIssue : IEnumerable<string>
```

and replace `GetEnumerator` with:

```
public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
{
  return issues.GetEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
  return GetEnumerator();
}
```

The scritp will fail with an error:

> Object Doesn't Support this Property or Method

My understanding is that the public `GetEnumerator()` is not exported, since it
is a generic method, and the `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` is not exported, since
my instance must first be casted to `IEnumerable` but in VBScript one cannot
cast objects.

Is this true?
Is it possible to tell the compiler that `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` should be
exported as `public IEnumerable GetEnumerator`? (Or does this statement make no
sense? etc.)

Comment: Scripting languages only support the default interface and don't provide a way to query another.  [Unless you provide the help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32405340/17034).  There is no point in trying to expose the generic interface, it will never be used.

Comment: a) Since the type library (http://pastebin.com/YiEwE3yT) did not change when changing the interface from `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<string>`, I naively assumed it wouldn't matter.

Comment: b) I thought, that essentially I "moved" `Mapper.ToEnum` to my class and renamed it to `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`. Now `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` is not callable as you explained. Therefore I asked: If I can make `GetEnumerator()` (or something newly created) callable from COM. I beg your pardon for being slow in
grasping the picture and thank you for the explanations your provided so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch which interface is implemented explicitly, such as:

```
IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<string>.GetEnumerator()
{
    // ...
}

public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    // ...
}
```

This is because [`IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` has the `DispId(-4)` attribute](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/ienumerable.cs,9be451ac13d86a97), which is what VBScript uses through `IDispatch.Invoke`.

Generic methods and methods with generic types are not COM visible, so if you don't want to change your code, define an extra method for COM:

```
// Test if the .NET framework dispatches the method if you apply the following attribute
//[ComVisible(false)]
[DispId(-4)]
public IEnumerator NewEnum()
{
    return ((IEnumerable)this).GetEnumerator();
}
```